# Migrating Email to new hosting

Tags: email, migration, hosting, pop3

I've made a site for a charity, and now have to move hosting for them. They have 5 or so email addresses on their current hosting account, which will of course need to move too.

What's the best way to migrate their email addresses to the new server without too much hassle for them?

They use POP3, so should I just create the account on the new server and then get them to update their settings? That won't remove their old emails from Outlook Express, will it?

Answer (score 2):

Changing the server Outlook Express connections to *shouldn't* delete the old e-mails. However, if you are worried take a backup copy of the old pst file first.